# Borrar un registro con PDO en Slim

Tags: php, json, pdo, slim

Estoy intentando ejecutar el siguiente código en **Slim V.4** para borrar un registro en `MariaDB` y no está sucediendo prácticamente nada.

¿Qué podría ser?

```
$app->delete('/app/user/delete/{id}', function (Response $response, Request $request, $args){
    $id = $args['id'];
    $sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = '$id'";
    try{
        $db = new db();
        $db = $db->connect();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute([$id]);
        $db = null;
        echo '{"notice": "Usuario borrado con éxito"}';
    }catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error": {"text": ' . $e->getMessage() . '}';
    }
});
```

En la consola de **insomnia** dice:

> INTERNAL SERVER ERROR 500.

Y en la consola **`Linux`**:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to {closure}() must
> implement interface Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface, instance of
> Slim\Psr7\Request given, called in
> /home/martyn/APP/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Handlers/Strategies/RequestResponse.php
> on line 42 and defined in /home/martyn/APP/src/routes/users.php:72
>
> Stack trace:
>
> *#0*
> /home/martyn/APP/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Handlers/Strategies/RequestResponse.php(42):
> {closure}(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request), Object(Slim\Psr7\Response),
> Array)
>
> *#1*
> /home/martyn/APP/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Routing/Route.php(372):
> Slim\Handlers\Strategies\RequestResponse->__invoke(Object(Closure),
> Object(Slim\Psr7\Request), Object(Slim\Psr7\Response), Array)
>
> *#2*
> /home/martyn/APP/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(73):
> Slim\Routing\Route->handle(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request)) #3
> /home/martyn/APP/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(73):
> Slim\MiddlewareDispatcher->handle(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request))
>
> *#4*
> /home/martyn/APP/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Routing/Route.php(333):
> Slim\MiddlewareDispatche in /home/martyn/APP/src/routes/users.php on
> line 72

Comment: No utilizo slim, pero estas pasando el id directamente en el prepare cuando deberia ser en el execute como array, es decir: el sql asi: `$sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = ?";` y el execute asi: `$stmt->execute([$id]);` . La parte del `$user= json_decode(...` en principio sobra

Comment: Sí, lo intenté y he visto varios tutoriales al respecto pero aún asi creo que el problema va de la mano con las rutas del framework.

Comment: por lo que comentas y echandole un vistazo a la documentacion la ruta deberia quedar con un tercer parametro para los argumentos, `$app->delete('/app/user/delete/{id}', function (Response $response, Request $request, $args){` Donde tendras disponible el id que se pasa en la ruta en `$args['id']`

Comment: Ahí intenté nuevamente de la forma que dices pero aún así persiste el error. La verdad, muy raro porque las otras consultas hechas a la base de datos no hubo problemas.

Comment: Pero te sigue dando el mismo error? Puedes añadir el archivo completo desde el principio?

Comment: Ahora lo copio y lo pego en la descripción del problema

Comment: @Xerif ahí está cargado el archivo completo!

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99099/discussion-between-xerif-and-martin-lc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La funcion anonima espera una instancia de `Response` y de `Request`

```
$app->delete('/app/user/delete/{id}', function (Response $response, Request $request, $args){/*...*/}
```

pero slim las pasa al reves, primero el `Request` y luego el `Response`

```
$app->delete('/app/user/delete/{id}', function (Request $request, Response $response, $args) {/*...*/}
```

Tambien tenemos que estas pasando el id directamente en el prepare en lugar de un marcador, el codigo podria quedar así:

```
// invertimos Reques y Response
$app->delete('/app/user/delete/{id}', function (Request $request, Response $response, $routeArguments) {
    // recuperamos el id de la ruta
    $id = $routeArguments['id'];
    $user= json_decode($request->getBody()->getContents(), true);
    // cambiamos $id por un marcador ?
    $sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = ?";
    try {
        $db = new db();
        $db = $db->connect();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        // cambiamos $user por un array que contine el id: [$id]
        $stmt->execute([$id]);
        $response->getBody()->write(json_encode($user));
        // añadimos el return
        return $response;
    }catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error": {"text": ' . $e->getMessage() . '}';
    }
});
```

Documentacion slim:

- [Routing](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/objects/routing.html#how-to-create-routes)